# "a bin target must be available for 'cargo run'"

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

While building a new Rust "Project from other sources", in Intellij IDEA 2017, I was unable to run the project through its UI.

> C:/Users/sjsui/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe run error: a bin target must be
>   available for `cargo run`
>
> Process finished with exit code 101

I noticed that no --bin target was provided by my build configuration so I placed the path to the projects target folder; same result.

[image]

> C:/Users/sjsui/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe run --bin C:\Users\sjsui\exercism\rust\hello-world\target\debug
>   error: no bin target named `C:\Users\sjsui\exercism\rust\hello-world\target\debug`

I tried creating a fresh Rust project through the Cargo command line interface, and received this error when running it:

> error: could not exec the linker `link.exe`: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
>   note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was
>   not found
>
> note: please ensure that VS 2013 or VS 2015 was installed with the
>   Visual C++ option

Evidently I must install Visual C++ build tools 2017 and am in the process of doing so. Are these errors related, or different issues?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, Cargo will consider the file `src/main.rs` to be the main binary target for the package. If this file doesn't exist, and there are no other binary targets defined in `Cargo.toml`, you'll get this error.

[According to the documentation](https://intellij-rust.github.io/docs/quick-start.html), when you create a Rust project in IntelliJ IDEA, you get an option to *Use a binary (application) template*. This should give you a `src/main.rs` instead of a `src/lib.rs` (which is the default root file for a library target). Using Cargo on the command line, you can also create an application package with [`cargo new hello`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/getting-started/first-steps.html).

> Cargo defaults to `--bin` to make a binary program. To make a library, we'd pass `--lib`.

When you use `--bin` on the `cargo run` command, the argument refers to one of the [`[[bin]]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/manifest.html#configuring-a-target) sections in `Cargo.toml`, or files following the pattern `src/bin/*.rs` (the argument replaces the `*`) if there are no `[[bin]]` sections in `Cargo.toml`. For example, `cargo run --bin foo` will either compile and run `src/bin/foo.rs` or the `[[bin]]` section with `name = "foo"` in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: My mistake was to forget that the project was created by importing from sources. (file > new > project from other sources). This source had only `lib.rs`; a library as you say.